# Time stamping of files in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, file-management, date-time, timestamp

I need to know the exact time I shot a video.  The video was shot with an iPhone and moved to a Windows 8 PC.

The Properties dialog in Windows tells me the following about this file:

Created: ‎Tuesday, ‎February ‎11, ‎2014, ‏‎11:05:27 PM
Modified: Tuesday, ‎February ‎11, ‎2014, ‏‎10:33:11 PM
Accessed: ‎Tuesday, ‎February ‎11, ‎2014, ‏‎11:05:27 PM

When was this video actually shot?

Answer (score 0):

Those are windows filesystem date/time stamps. You need to view the Exif (Exchangeable image file format) data which 'should' be embedded into the file itself. Try using an online program such as:

http://exifdata.com/

Simply upload the photo/video and it will tell you whatever information it can find.

However, looking at those time stamps you've given, considering that the Modified Date/Time is BEFORE the Created and Accessed Date/Times, then we can gather that it was copied from some location to a new folder at 11:05:27 PM (when copying a file to a new location, windows changes the created/accessed date/time to the current date/time, however when moving a file it leaves them unchanged).

Therefore, if you haven't modified the file in any way after uploading it to the computer, the modified time that it displays 10:33:11 PM should be the time the video was shot.

Comment: I didn't realize iPhone videos had EXIF information.  Are there any Windows utilities that will allow viewing it?  exifdata.com won't allow me to upload a large video.

Comment: Yes they do, however there is no clearly defined set of rules when it comes to embedding Exif data in video files (as opposed to image files).

After doing a quick test run with my iphone and transferring to computer after a period of time, i have confirmed that as i mentioned previously, it is the `modified time` that is the actual time the video file was created.

Comment: As for the viewing the data, i just realized that depending on what version of windows you are using, by right clicking and choosing properties, if you have a 'details' tab that will display all the Exif data that can be found in the file. (I can't believe i didn't mention this originally!!)

Comment: The Details tab is actually not showing any useful metadata for this file (other than resolution and the stuff we already knew from file properties).  But I opened the video in Media Player Classic and was able to see EXIF and other metadata by right-clicking the playback screen and going to Properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a small amount of searching for you, and it seems so far that this is a known issue, the apple products have a tendency to use the modified date as the actual creation date and the creation date and a modified date, problem is all of the fixes I can find so far for this are for Macs, not iPhone, one thing you might want to look at is the settings on the phone, it was suggested (for a mac) that if you are not using your automatic time update settings correctly and or the location services correctly the phone takes a guess based off of the listed time zone controls, this can cause an issue, but like I said, this was for the Mac not the iPhone, so it might not apply,

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5894743
https://discussions.apple.com/message/20670429#20670429

I hope this helps you out some bit.